# What webpack loader do I have to use to combine media queries?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, webpack, webpack-style-loader

In order to combine media queries, what webpack loader do I have to use, or there is no such a loader for now?
In my projects, I use style-loader, css-loader, postcss-loader, and sass-loader to build stylesheets. However none of them combine media queries.
I just need a webpack loader just like grunt/gulp-combine-media-queries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this plugin for postcss: https://github.com/hail2u/node-css-mqpacker

Comment: @bob-sponge Using the plugin, I finally fixed the issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry but, can i include this module in webpack ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack loader for combine media queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744632/webpack-loader-for-combine-media-queries)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [css-mqpacker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-mqpacker), it could also be used as a PostCSS plugin.

Here is an example of postcss.config.js file in a webpack project.

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('autoprefixer')({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 11']
        }),
        require("css-mqpacker"),
        require('cssnano')({ zindex: false })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The [CSSO](https://github.com/css/csso) with its `forceMediaMerge` option is a way without any additional plugin.

> Enables merging of @media rules with the same media query by splitted by other rules. The optimisation is unsafe in general, but should work fine in most cases. Use it on your own risk.