# Webpack loader for combine media queries?

Tags: webpack

Do you know if there is a module that allows combine media queries with Webpack ?

For grunt or gulp, i know [this module](https://github.com/frontendfriends/grunt-combine-mq) but It is not on webpack.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

After looking at `postcss-move-media`; I noticed that it's just an empty shell project, that doesn't actually do anything.

I found another PostCSS plugin that seems to do the trick though.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-mqpacker

Note that the package has been deprecated by the author, so use it with caution.

---

#### Step 1

Install it from NPM.

```
npm install css-mqpacker --save-dev
```

#### Step 2

Include it in your PostCSS config.
That can be either `postcss.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
    /* ... */
    plugins: {
        'cs-mqpacker': {},
    },
};
```

Or, if you use Laravel Mix, via the options key:

```js
mix.sass('resources/sass/styles.scss', 'public/css')
.options({
    postCss: [
        require('css-mqpacker'),
    ],
});
```